# How to Flatten a Collection of Objects with Flag Enum Properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a `Role` object that will have several flag enum properties, one for each related object. A user can belong to multiple roles. I want to get the collection of roles and flatten it to a single representation and use that to limit UI features. How do I flatten the collection?

Here's some example code from my LINQPad test:

```
ICollection<Role> roles = new List<Role>();

roles.Add(new Role {
    Name = "Administrator",
    Object1Defaults = DefaultPermissions.Add | DefaultPermissions.Edit | DefaultPermissions.Remove,
    Object2Defaults = DefaultPermissions.Add | DefaultPermissions.Edit | DefaultPermissions.Remove
});
roles.Add(new Role {
    Name = "Manager",
    Object1Defaults = DefaultPermissions.Add | DefaultPermissions.Edit,
    Object2Defaults = DefaultPermissions.Add | DefaultPermissions.Edit
});

public class Role {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DefaultPermissions Object1Defaults { get; set; }
    public DefaultPermissions Object2Defaults { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum DefaultPermissions {
    Add = 1 << 0,
    Edit = 1 << 1,
    Remove = 1 << 2
}
```

Of course, I'm also open to suggestions for better ways to implement permissions. My plan was to have an enum for each other object in the database in the `Role` go off of that in each view just like with `Object1Defaults` and `Object2Defaults` except with better names and many more of them.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd recommend not using enums as Flags. It limits how many you can have total, which may not be an issue now, but will be a big issue if you run out of bits later down the road.  So make your permissions container a collection.

Once you do that, using linq, it's pretty easy to flatten the result into an array (or List, or whatever you want):

```
var result = roles.SelectMany(x => Object1Defaults).Distinct().ToArray();
```